# Periodicity of solution of a differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

> Consider the equation $$y'+a(x)y=b(x)$$
>   where $a$ and $b$ are continuous real valued functions on $\Bbb R$ which are of period $\xi>0$, and $b$ is not identically zero. Show that a function $\phi$ is periodic of period $\xi$ iff $\phi(0)=\phi(\xi)$.

**My attempts**

Only if part is trivial. I am struggling with the if part. I have evaluated the general solution to be 
$$\phi(x)=cA(x)+A(x)\int_0^x\dfrac{b(x)}{A(x)}\mathrm dx$$
$$A(x):=e^{-\int_0^xa(x)\mathrm dx}$$

$c$ is the constant of integration.

But periodicity of a function doesn't imply the periodicity of its integral, hence $A(x)$ may or may not be periodic. This is creating a problem.

Please help.

Comment: The integral over $[x,x+\xi]$ is periodic. And so is the integral in $[0,x]$ minus $x$ times the average over a period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $ϕ(0)=ϕ(ξ)$, then $ϕ_1(x)=ϕ(x+ξ)$ satisfies the same ODE as $ϕ$, as the coefficients are periodic, and has the same initial value as $ϕ$. By the uniqueness theorem, $ϕ$ and $ϕ_1$ have to be identical solutions. Thus $ϕ(x)=ϕ_1(x)=ϕ(x+ξ)$ everywhere, which means that $ϕ$ is periodic with period $ξ$.

Comment: Thank you very much!